# receiving sparkcontext error while initializing sparksession

Tags: scala, apache-spark, emr

I am receiving sparkcontext error while starting sparksession on EMR 5.3.1 in scala. Below is the version of spark I am using and the error.
This works fine on windows machine but errors out on EMR. Also is this the right way to create sparksession?

spark_version: 2.1.0

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("vierweship_test")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "target/spark-warehouse") 
  //.enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

Error:

```
17/08/01 13:08:14 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
```

I get below error if i do not use warehouse directory properties.

```
17/08/01 13:00:02 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.addDistributedUri$1(Client.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$distribute$1(Client.scala:476)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$11$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(Client.scala:599)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.foreach(ArraySeq.scala:74)
```

Command I am using :

```
spark-submit --verbose --class xxx --master yarn --jars="s3-dist-cp.jar:common-0.1.jar" --deploy-mode client --packages "Xxx:xxx:XXx" myjar-0.1.jar
```

Comment: Have you setup HADOOP environment ?

Comment: No , Do we need to set it before we create spark-session? Do you know what are the basic setup I need to do?

Comment: For running in local mode it is not required, I just want to know if you have installed it or not?

Comment: I didn't mean to running it locally, i am running it on EMR and I want to run it in distributed mode. This is just a code snippet i found somewhere

Comment: How do you submit your spark application?

Comment: Added command in the question

Comment: Hi , I have edited my question with the command I am using.

Comment: Begin the address of warehouse with `file://`.